# Database structure like wufoo

Tags: database, database-design, webforms

I am trying to build a dynamic forms app like [wufoo](http://wufoo.com/). Creating new table for each form is definitely not a good approach. Form fields can be boolean, enum, varchar or text.

Should I make separate table for each datatype and manage them via one parent table? or is there any better approach than this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is Wuforms? could you give more information? If you describe a litle your system specification, I believe we can help.

Comment: Sorry, it was wufoo not wuforms. I have made the update. Please check http://wufoo.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NoSQL databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) are an alternative to relational databases management systems.  Typically they allow you to store a collection of key-value pairs.  This approach might be very appropriate for your requirements.